# N-Queens queen is safe infinite loop

Tags: java, n-queens

I am solving n-queen,  but i have a problem for some reason the while loop keeps looping without iterating, tempx and tempy doesn't go up by i/j. and the result keeps outputting 0,0

```
public static boolean isSafe(Board board, int row, int col){
    int tempx;
    int tempy;

    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i ++){
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j ++){
            try {
                tempx = row + i;
                tempy = col + j;
                while(tempx >= 0 && tempx < board.getRow() && tempy >= 0 && tempy < board.getRow()) {

                    if(board.getTile(tempx, tempy).isOccupied())
                        return false;
                    tempx += i;
                    tempy += j;
                } 
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok i figured it out and it seems to work fine, for anyone that wants to know here it is, please correct me if there is a better way of doing this

```
public static boolean isSafe(Board board, int row, int col){
    int tempx;
    int tempy;

    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i ++){
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j ++){
            try {
                tempx = row + i;
                tempy = col + j;
                for(int k = 0; k < board.getRow(); k++){
                    if(tempx >= 0 && tempx < 8 && tempy >= 0 && tempy < 8) {

                        if(board.getTile(tempx, tempy).isOccupied() )
                            return false;


                        tempx += i;
                        tempy += j; 

                    } 
                }


            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: check your 3rd while loop condition , it should be like that **while((tempx >= 0 && tempx < 8) && (tempy >= 0 && tempy < 8))**

Comment: Do you ***really*** want to use `||` in your `while` loop?

Comment: I tried that its still giving me the same result

Comment: ok i figured it out it works now i added the code

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that the loop

```
while(tempx >= 0 || tempx < 8 || tempy >= 0 || tempy < 8) {
```

is *infinite* as for *every* number `tempx` and `tempy` it is satisfied?

You probably wanted

```
while(tempx >= 0 && tempx < 8 && tempy >= 0 && tempy < 8) {
```